# Equivalence constants for induced matrix norms

Tags: matrices, operator-norms

*Disclaimer: I asked this question beforehand on mathematics stack exchange, but I think it is better suited for this site*

---

Given two sets $P_i\in\mathbb{R}^s$, bounded, convex, with non-empty interior and such that $\lambda P_i\subseteq P_i$ for all $|\lambda |\leq 1$, $i=1,2$.
Let $\|\,\cdot\,\|_{P_i}$ be the vector norms whose unit balls are $P_i$,
and consider the corresponding induced matrix norms $|||\cdot\, |||_{P_i}$.

Since all norms in $\mathbb{R}^s$ are equivalent, there exist constants $A,B>0$ such that
$$
A|||M|||_{P_1} \leq |||M|||_{P_2} \leq B|||M|||_{P_1}
$$
for all matrices $M\in\mathbb{R}^{s\times s}$.

**My question:** Is there anything known about how to compute good$^{(1)}$ constants $A,B$?
For simplicity I can assume that the sets $P_i$ are either

1. symmetric convex hulls of finitely many points (i.e. *polytopes*), or the
2. convex hulls of linear images of ellipses in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I assume that for 2. the problem is quite impossible, but I hope that for 1. there is some literature (or even the problem is trivial but I just don´t see it).

---

$^{(1)}$ *Good* means: Better constants than those which are obtained by using the constants $a,b>0$ from the underlying vector norms, i.e. the constants such that for all vectors $v\in\mathbb{R}^s$ it holds that
$$
a||v||_{P_1} \leq ||v||_{P_2} \leq b||v||_{P_1},
$$
and then setting $A=a/b$ and $B=b/a$.